# Best way to organize data in HDF5 file

Tags: python, matlab, bigdata, hdf5

I'm looking for a way to organize my scientific data efficiently. Probably this will be done in HDF5, as this seems very convenient, but I'm open for alternatives. The only constraint is accessability for MATLAB and Python.

My data is in priciple hierarchical and looks as follows(all data is unsigned integer):

```
ID1|
   |ModuleNumber1|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |ModuleNumber2|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |
   ....
   |ModuleNumberX|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns

ID2
   |ModuleNumber1|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |ModuleNumber2|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |
   ....
   |ModuleNumberX|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
....
IDX
   |ModuleNumber1|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |ModuleNumber2|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
   |
   ....
   |ModuleNumberX|
   |             |Table with 300 rows and 10 columns
```

On first glance this seems pretty clear. Just use HDF5 to model this hierarchicality like

/ID/ModuleNumber/

and put a table inside.
But this seems to be slow when I retrieve the data in our typical use case way, which is as follows:

1. Make a database query (in a seperate PostgreSQL database where metadata is stored on a per module basis) for suitable IDs and ModuleNumbers (data postselection)
2. Get the data of a whole column of the fitting ID/ModuleNumbers as an array. The data in this column inside every fitting module is added to the current data in the array to calculate a mean value of a specific cell over many modules.

As this use case is very specific there is probably a better way to organize my data than the obvious hierarchical one.

For example the ID is not really important and only used for postselection purposes. One could make the ID an attribute of ModuleNumber to reduce the number of layers but then there would be the need of a global counting of ModuleNumbers which is not really compatible with the database layout.

I also could imagine a completely flat layout without hierarchy where there are additional columns for ID and ModuleNumber.

But until now I'm pretty unsatisfied with my ideas, maybe anyone could help me with better ones.

PS: The size we are talking about are several thousand tables and file sizes between 100MB-1G. The goal is to be as fast as possible when reading. The files are read-only and will not be modified after initial creation.

Best,

Nico

Comment: What kind of performance are you getting from reading the HDF5 file? About how long does it take to read what you want? I typically use files on that order of size and they are fairly quick to load. I typically name each array like the following /ID_ModuleNumber instead of /ID/ModuleNumber.

Can you copy/paste some of your code here so we can see the options you have selected for your HDF5 as well? It would help to know if there is any compression, among other things.